# Вызов метода класса без создания экземпляра

Tags: python

В PHP есть возможность вызвать метод класса, без создания экземпляра, например, `UsefulClass::useful_method($argument)` вместо `$instance = new UsefulClass(); $instance->useful_method($argument)`. В питоне есть такая возможность?

Comment: Hint: общее название таких методов в ООП - статические методы.

Comment: Если пошел такой ликбез, есть ли какой-то специальный профит от использования статических методов или специальная область применения?

Comment: Бывает удобно, если хочется в функции обрабатывать множество экземпляров одного класса, но и выносить эту логику из класса не хочется, тогда делаем метод с декоратором staticmethod и вызываем его как обычную функцию с любыми аргументами (в нее не будет передаваться экземпляр первым параметром), а сама функция остается в пространстве имен класса и везде у нас порядочек.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Декоратор

```
@classmethod
```

Comment: Или `@staticmethod` если контекст не важен.

Answer (score 1):

Если пытаетесь вызвать метод предка в классе-потомке - super()

Comment: Тоже бывает полезно)